# How to render a component when a specific component will render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

This is the sample code:

```
<Route exact path='/user'>
    <UsersList />
</Route>
<Route path='/user/:name'>
    <Sidebar />
    <User />
</Route>
```

- `UsersList` component is like a *home/landing page*.
- `UsersList` and `Sidebar` both the components contains list of links. When we click any of the link, we will be redirected to that **users page**.
- `User` component will render the information of that specific **user**.

Let say we are on `/user/john` and want go on `/user/jack`. But when I am doing this i.e. when I am clicking on the link to go from `/user/john` to `/user/jack`, React is re-rendering the `Sidebar` component.

But I want that `Sidebar` component should render **only once** and **only when `path='/user/:name'`**. So, how to do it?

Comment: If you will add a link or sample of your code to provide  more accurate solution.

Comment: The `Sidebar` will always be re-rendered. When the URL changes, but if its something you want to save, you can save it in its `constructor` or `componentDidMount` functions (don't use setState here). Since those functions are called once

Answer (score 1):

To realize what you really want, you need to use layout.

If you introduce layout, it would be look like this.

```
<container>
    <appbar>
    </appbar>
    <content>
        <sidebar>
        </sidebar>
        <Route path='/user/:name'>
        </Route>
    </content>
</container>
```

For example take a look at [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/layout-components/). (You need to search the demo based on the framework you are using)

Answer (score 1):

If you can move the `Sidebar` component out the `Route` component, then use the [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) shorthand tag as a parent component for all the `JSX` elements.

So you should use this

```
<>
  <Sidebar />
  <Route path='/user/:name'>
    <User />
  </Route>
</>
```